# 'git clone' respects umask, except for top level project directory

Tags: linux, git, permissions

I would like to clone a git project (from github, say), and have the top level directory be writable by group.

I tried a couple different things.  First, just setting the umask before cloning.

```
$ umask
0002
```

Files that I create are then writable by group

```
$ touch test
$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 2012-05-17 09:32 test
```

Now I try `git clone`

```
$ git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
Cloning into repo... [succeeds]
```

But the clone directory not writable by group.

```
$ ls -ld repo
drwxr-xr-x 11 user group 4096 2012-05-17 09:32 repo
```

I tried the same thing with a repo created with `git init --shared=umask` (which should already be the default) in a directory with 775 permissions.  After pushing to github `git clone` gets the same results.

This isn't a huge deal, I can chmod in my checkout scripts.  But if there's a right/builtin way to do this, that's preferable.  Git is version 1.7.4.1 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Any ideas or links are appreciated.  I saw [this post, but it uses chmod](https://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine), I haven't been able to find much else on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the global "core.sharedRepository=group" just for the clone command:

```
git -c "core.sharedRepository=group" clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
ls -ld repo/.git
drwxrwsr-x 8 user user 4096 Jul  4 22:16 repo/.git/
```

Comment: Hey @fork0, thanks for the reply.  My .git directory and all project files are already group writeable, thanks to my umask.  To clarify, I'm trying to have the project top level directory be group writeable (ie `ls -ld repo` would show `drwxrwxr-x`).  Setting `core.sharedRepository=group` does the same thing as `git init --shared=group` behind the scenes, and does not make the top level directory writeable by group.

Comment: Yes, it cannot. The creation of clone destination directory is an unconditional `mkdir(work_tree, 0755)`. I am not sure it is intentional, so I'm going to ask on git mailing list. Meanwhile, you can change the mkdir to use 0777 in builtin/clone.c

Comment: your last comment hit the nail on the head.  This is not currently possible.  Thanks!

Comment: @r_2: only currently. It is being fixed, a patch is already submitted. Commit id in the official repo: 45d4fdc2dc74c657a9c2e95bf04aed539fdcb0a4. Not accepted in mainline yet, but looks good.

Comment: Can you please update your question to reflect the fact that you currently /cannot/? Thanks.

Comment: @AntonyStubbs: Did you mean "update the _answer_"? Besides, the commit is already in the mainline, since v1.7.11.3, so "you currently can".

Comment: @fork0 I am not entirely sure, but I think I am having the same problem as well: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80267/9610 -- do you think the bug fix hasn't yet made it to the Debian package?

Comment: @its_me: Could be. Debian is still on 1.7.10

Comment: @fork0 just hit myself with that, Debian 7.7 still runs 1.7.10.4.

Comment: It's a pity that even today (2023) with Git 2.39.0, `git clone` lacks direct support for `--shared=group`. But this is probably because unfortunately `--shared` means something *completely different* in `git clone` and `git init`. Which probably would have helped here as well. Meh. So thanks @fork0 for the idea to use configuration settings on the commandline when cloning.

Answer (score 3):

This was due to a bug, fixed in git >= v1.7.11.3

See:
https://github.com/git/git/commit/45d4fdc2dc74c657a9c2e95bf04aed539fdcb0a4